# How to do conditional query in Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

The situation is following.
The table has 2 date fields and last date is nullable.

[image]

In this table I want to get the 1st and 2nd records when I pass 2020-02-10 as parameter. That is between start_end and end_date or bigger than start_date if end_date is null.

How to do Laravel eloquent for this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of ugly, but I think something like that should work

```php
Model::where(function($query) use ($date){
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)
        ->where('end_date', '>=',  $date);
})->orWhere(function($query) use ($date) {
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)
        ->whereNull('end_date');
})->get()
```

**Edit**
Since you need other condition with it, you need to wrap this condition

````php
Model::query()
->where(function($query) use ($date) {
    $query->where(function($query) use ($date){
        $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)
            ->where('end_date', '>=',  $date);
    })->orWhere(function($query) use ($date) {
        $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)
            ->whereNull('end_date');
    })
})
->where('another_column', true)
->get()
```
````

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. If I have another fields like is_deleted and I should check the field how to implement multiple condition?

Comment: You need to wrap the `where` and the `orWhere` in an another `where(function($query){....}` (three level deep) See the anonymous function as parenthesis.